# PHP $_POST values

Tags: php, variables, post, for-loop

i have a little problem with storing the $_POST data, think i might be confusing myself a little.

So i have some data being posted from a loop, this data is posted as id and points, but each has a number to it so if three records are being posted we'll have

id1, id2, id3
points1, points2, points3

to collect. Now i'm using a for loop to go through the data and post it into two arrays to work with. The problem is When I want to store the data i have to use one of the names listed above ie id1 or id2. Here is my code

```
for($i = 0; i< $_POST['count']; i++){
    //Order input data into an array
    $inputid[$i] = $_POST['id1'];

}
```

Now the number part of the 'id' of the $_POST['id1'] has to be the same as $i in the for loop so it will increment as the loop does.

Thanks for the help and i hope i explained the question right.

Comment: You can create the array key before using it: `$_POST['id' . $i]; // Key = id1.` However, `$_POST['count']` is `6`, but `id3` is the last `id` value passed via the `$_POST` array. Your approach may not be the most suitable (hint: *[Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)*).

Comment: Looks like you are using post data directly.  You should sanitize it first before using it.  Here is an example of one way of doing it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; i< $_POST['count']; i++){
    //Order input data into an array
    $inputid[$i] = $_POST['id'.$i];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not name the inputs: `name="id[1]"` and `name="points[1]"` so you'll have `$_POST['id'][...]` and `$_POST['points'][...]` arrays to work with?

Reference: [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) (specifically [Example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-99)).

Comment: So the array is made when the posting is done? Do you know of any more examples of this so i could look into it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use POST variables in loops or anything else unless you've checked them out first to make sure they don't contain anything nasty.

You could try this within the loop:

```
$idnumber = "id" . $i;
$inputid[$i] = $_POST[$idnumber];
```

Comment: jensgram - thank you sir, I've been doing lots of Javascript today and always get concat operators mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate the string in the index:

```
for($i = 0; i< $_POST['count']; i++){
    //Order input data into an array
    $inputid[$i] = $_POST['id' . ($i+1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not going wrong you want the posted id same as the increment var $i try this out

```
for($i = 0; $i< $_POST['count']; $i++){
    $post_id = 'id'.$i;
    $inputid[$i] = $_POST[$post_id];

}
```

Comment: This seems to break the whole script! :S

Comment: i have changed the way of generating the post_id. **One question about the starting of post variable id is it starts from 0 or 1 ?  if it's one you should start your loop from $i = 1**

Comment: I got it working and it was my own dump fault! :( Well after you help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question, there are already a known amount of inputs that are going to be posted, so I don't understand why you need a loop at all for adding them to the array. Why not do this:

```
$value = array($_POST['id1'], $_POST['id2'], $_POST['id3'], $_POST['points1'], $_POST['points2'], $_POST['points3']);
```

than loop like this:

```
for(x=0;x<$value.count;x++){
    $value[x]=$value.$x;
}
```

That should work

Comment: No the amount isn't known, so i can't hard code it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go for something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i< $_POST['count']; $i++){
//Order input data into an array
$inputid[$i] = $_POST["id$i"];
}
```

Is this what you want?